# Configurating an archiva repository to never allow to update a old version of an artifact

Tags: apache, maven, archiva

Due a requirement of one of our clients We need garantee that our developers can not update a published version of an artifact in Archiva. They will be enable to publish a new version of the same artifact.

Is it possible to have  this configuration in archiva?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As an administrator, click the "Repositories" link on the left, then "Edit" the managed repository you wish to configure it for. You will find the option "Block Re-deployment of Released Artifacts". This option is available on version 1.3 and above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is exactly that we need. We will upgrade to 1.3.5 to have this option.